# How to use FFmpeg to register certain Codecs?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I want to use  H264 decoder in FFmpeg only. How to register it instead of using following codes.Thank you in advance.

```
avcodec_register_all();
codec=avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_H264);  // find the decoder with the corresponding FCC
```

Comment: Have you tried using the above code? Is it working? If not, what does not work?

Answer (score 1):

A `avcodec_register` call is going to register an individual codec instead of registering all available with `avcodec_register_all`. See libavcodec\allcodecs.c for how ffmpeg does it itself.